# Wait till user typing in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, settimeout

**I am trying to wait console.log, till user stops the typing, but its typing only 1st char only**

This is my code

```
let chnnelTimer;

onNameChangeHandler = (event) => {
clearTimeout(channnelTimer);
let name= event.target.value;

channnelTimer = setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(channelName);
  });
}, 500);
};
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal, reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You should use `let name= event.target.value;` inside setTimeout logic.

Comment: How do you know when the user has finished typing? Use `change` event or `_.debounce` or a *typing done* confirmation through a button click.